# How to add a configurable product to existing order in magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, magento2, configurable-product

How to add a configurable product to existing order in magento 2 ?

Comment: Please provide more details and what have you already tried and the problems you have encountered

Comment: adding items to existing orders is against many accounting regulations. Normally an order get cancelled and a new one will be created with desired changes applied. Adding items to cart/quote is a better choice, if it is an option